# How to send Midi messages to a midi controller in python

Tags: python, midi

I want to send midi messages in python to my [Mpk Mini 2](https://www.akaipro.com/mpk-mini-mkii) (a midi controller) but I don't find how to do that. The only tutorials I found explain how to receive messages, not how to send them.

With MidiView app, I saw the messages I had to send. The only problem is I don't know how to do it

And I got my ports

```py
midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
available_ports = midiout.get_ports()
print(available_ports)
```

it returned:
`['Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth 0', 'MPKmini2 1']`

What I would like to do is send a midi message to the keyboard so that its pads flash. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [example](https://spotlightkid.github.io/python-rtmidi/rtmidi.html#usage-example) of sending a MIDI message in the documentation of *rtmidi* that you can follow to accomplish what you want.

With your MidiView app, if you already have the message, you can send it like that, with `send_message()` method:

```
midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
available_ports = midiout.get_ports()

if available_ports:
    midiout.open_port('MPKmini2 1')

with midiout:
    # This is an example of message, change it according your needs
    # with the MIDI message you get from MidiView
    note_on = [0x90, 60, 112] # channel 1, middle C, velocity 112
    note_off = [0x80, 60, 0]
    # Here you send the message to the device
    midiout.send_message(note_on)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    # Here you send the stop message
    midiout.send_message(note_off)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

(0x90 is Note-on message, 0x80 is Note-off)

Comment: I've got this error: 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    midiout.open_port('MPKmini2 1')
  File "src\_rtmidi.pyx", line 549, in rtmidi._rtmidi.MidiBase.open_port
TypeError: an integer is required```

Comment: Try with `midiout.open_port(1)`. In the doc, I read we can open port by name, but if it doesn't work, just pass the port number returned by `get_ports()`, `1` in your case.

Comment: the name of the midi device is 'MPKmini2' only.
Try with :

`midiout.open_port('MPKmini2')`